# How to strip the following date time from a string?

Tags: python

I want to strip the date-time from the following string in Python 3:

So What I do is the following:

```
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime("06/30/16(Thu)12:41:05",'%d/%m/%y(%a)%H:%M:%S')
```

But I get a value error which means the format is not the one.

Comment: the format should be `%m/%d/%y(%a)%H:%M:%S`

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your import is correct:

```py
from datetime import datetime
```

(rather than just `import datetime`)
Then use the correct format string:

```py
datetime.strptime("06/30/16(Thu)12:41:05", "%m/%d/%y(%a)%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is Simple!
First you can have to import *datetime* . You can done this by

**from datetime import datetime**

And your format of Month and Day needs to be swapped (d and m)

**date_time_obj = datetime.strptime("06/30/16(Thu)12:41:05",'%m/%d/%y(%a)%H:%M:%S')**